# Spree API Endpoints and Checkout Workflow

Tags: api, checkout, single-page-application, spree

We wanted to create a Spree app where the entire front-end is a single-page app.
What is the recommended approach for this?

As part of the same, we were exploring the Spree API endpoints required to be used from the front-end.
Are there any references or guides we can follow, particularly on the implementation of the checkout process?

We couldn't find any API documentation on creation of shipping address and billing address during the checkout process.

- We tried sending a **POST** request to the **addresses API** controller, but there were only the **show** and **update** methods there
- We tried a **PUT** request on the **orders API** controller by passing parameters such as **orders['bill_address_attributes']['...'], orders['bill_address']['...']**, but we received status **422**.
- We also tried a **POST** request at **/checkout/update/address**, but we got **route not found error**.

We have not been able to find a method to create shipping and billing addresses in the **'address'** phase of the checkout flow.

Are there further references where we can find details on this?
Any pointers to documentation or source code regarding the above would be of great help.

Answer (score 2):

The checkout workflow is a little tricky, but going through each step of the checkout process defined [here](http://guides.spreecommerce.com/api/checkouts.html) will work.

But, I'm sure you've looked at that and it isn't so easy to follow, but not to fear, Spree has a walkthrough online that will make it easier to soak up:

https://github.com/radar/spree_api_examples/blob/master/examples/checkout/walkthrough.rb